# layout issues - footer colliding with picture

Tags: html, css

[image]

I originally thought this issue was bootstrap related because before my front end left he said he used bootstrap but float clear doesn't seem to be fixing it or im just lost. It turns out that it

here is the css

```
     .container {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 1200px;
  }
  .content-overlap {
    background: rgb(245, 244, 239);
    width: 40%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 80px;
    padding: 60px;
  }

  .content-overlap-right {
    background: rgb(245, 244, 239);
    width: 40%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 80px;
    right : 0px;
    padding: 60px;

  }
  .content-overlap:before {
    content: "";
    border: 2px solid rgba(171, 154, 124, 1.0);
    position: absolute;
    top: -10px;
    left: -10px;
    right: -10px;
    bottom: -10px;
  }

  .content-overlap-right:before {
    content: "";
    border: 2px solid rgba(171, 154, 124, 1.0);
    position: absolute;
    top: -10px;
    left: -10px;
    right: -10px;
    bottom: -10px;

  }
  .image-overlap {
    width: 70%;
    float: right;
  }

  .image-overlap-left {
    width: 70%;
    float: left;
  }
  @media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .content-overlap {
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
    }
    .image-overlap {
      width: 100%;
    }

    .content-overlap-right {
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
    }
    .image-overlap-right {
      width: 100%;
    }
  }

.footie {
    background: black;
    color: wheat;
    bottom: 0%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Here is the html

```
    `<div class="container">
  <div class="content-overlap">
    <h2>Contact Us</h2>
      <p> For investment information call: <br>
        +number or +NUMBER <br> <br>
          For legal contact:+NUMBER <br>
          For partnership: +NUMBER <br>
                  </p>
  </div>
  <div class="image-overlap">
    <img src="assets\administration.jpg"  >
  </div>
</div>
```

`

I think it might have to do with positioning but i don't know how to make it look the same.

all i want is for the footer not to collide with the contact us text box.

now it is asking me to add detail but i dont have much more to add. I actually asked this yesterday but I gave the wrong context since i was given the wrong context)

The footer is supposed to be rendering as a partial at the bottom , not colliding.

Comment: you need to add the HTML .. CSS alone is useless

Comment: Yeah sorry - edited in ! :)

Comment: my front end grabbed this from a codepen and all i want is for all that code to respect the footer , i tried setting margin top (for my footer class )but i realized that would only format well in some cases and not be a permafix.I think what i need is for the footer to just appear under all elements no matter what and i dont know how to do that.

Comment: Fix 'footie' to the bottom. `.footie { position:fixed; bottom: 0; width:100%; background: black; colour: wheat }`

Comment: that wont make it scroll with me right?

Comment: i ask because i want it at the bottom of all elements no matter whats in the middle but not to scroll

Comment: I dont want it to scroll with the user , i just want it to be the last displaying element and respect all elements above it.

Comment: like it seems to know the picture is there but ignores the textbox and i want it under the text box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it played out that my footer was in layouts - there was no easy way to set up a style sheet to affect it individually (as any style sheet would affect all layouts it seems) so I ended up styling the bottom margin of the previous element, therefore, pushing the whole thing down.

Thank you all for your assistance.